# Installing 2 Oracle DBs in same machine

Tags: oracle

How do I install both Oracle 10g XE and Oracle 11G XE on the same machine?

While installing I'm getting the following error.

[image: Install error]

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because AFAIK Oracle XE always uses the fixed service name XE. Therefore, you will get a name clash for the windows services, since both will be named "OracleServiceXE". Why do you want to do this? (Personally, I'd go for two virtual machines)

Comment: actually in my project i started with oracle 10g but there are some additional features in 11g(like pivot tables, list aggregate etc...), so i wanted to use 11g . now halfg of my project is done, but to see a demo of pivot tables i want to install 11g. how do i install both of them?

Comment: @Rakesh:`If you want see 11g features only`,then go to www.sqlfiddle.com or Apex Oracle `http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it , we need to disable the antivirus before installing and we can't install both Oracle 10G XE and 11G XE on same machine, but can install oracle 10gxe and 11g on same machine.